# MOBX Default, editable state derived from other states

Tags: javascript, mobx, mobx-react

Say I have a form where a user needs to add his personal information (name, first name and mail), enter a product, an amount, a color and a reason.

```
class Store {
    constructor(){
        extendObservable(this, {
             name : '', 
             firstName : '', 
             mail: '', 
             product : '', 
             amount: 0, 
             color: '', 
             reason : '',
             // computed functions & actions... 
        })
    }
}
```

react component (reason):

```
const Reason = observer(class Reason extends Component {
    onChange = (e) => {
        this.props.store.setReason(e.target.value);
    };  

    render () {
        const reason = this.props.store.reason;

        return (
             <textarea
                id="reason"
                name="reason"
                className="form-control"
                required={true}
                onChange={this.onChange}
                rows="2"
                value={reason}
             />
        );
    }
});
```

If I want to add a default reason, something like `Hi ${firstName}, you asked for ${amount} X ${color} ${product}`, how would I do that. I can't use a computed function for this, because the user must be able to overwrite the reason. off course, every time a user updates one of the fields that are displayed in the default string, the default string needs to update.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a computed for this. You could use a boolean to check if the user has changed the reason.

**Example ([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/suhutehede/edit?js,output))**

```
class State {
  @observable reason = '';
  @observable editedReason = false;
  @observable firstname = 'Carl';
  @observable amount = 2;
  @observable color = 'red';
  @observable product = 'car';
  @computed get computedReason() {
    return this.editedReason
      ? this.reason
      : `Hi ${this.firstname}, you asked for ${this.amount} X ${this.color} ${this.product}`;
  }
}

const state = new State();

@observer
class App {
  onChange = (e) => {
    state.editedReason = true;
    state.reason = e.target.value;
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <textarea
        onChange={this.onChange}
        value={state.computedReason}
      />
    </div>;
  }
}
```